# converting a text file into a vector in R

Tags: r

I have a text file in the following format: `elt1\telt2\t...` with 1,000,000 elements.
Most of these elements are integers, but some of them are of the form number_number or chainOfCharacters. For example: `1\t2\t2_3\t4_44\t2\t'sap'\t34\t'stack'` should output: `1 2 2_3 4_44 2 'sap' 34 'stack'`.I tried to load this data in R using `data <- read.table(file(fileName),row.names=0,sep='\t')` but it is taking for ever. Is it possible to speed this up?

Comment: I waited for 10 minutes and them interrupted the program

Comment: there is only one row...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use `scan` instead:

```
scan(fileName, character(), quote = "")
# Read 8 items
# [1] "1"     "2"     "2_3"     "4_44"    "2"     "'sap'"   "34"    "'stack'"
```

Comment: some of the elements in my text file are not numbers (like 1_2) so I got the following error: scan() expected a 'real', got '1_2'

Comment: @teaLeef, Please edit your question with sample data of sufficient complexity. If it is not "1,000,000 numbers." then don't write that.

Comment: It does't output the elements of the text file. Instead I get 1 2 3 4 etc

Comment: @teaLeef What is the desired result for your example string `1\t2\t2_3\t4_44\t2\t'sap'\t34\t'stack'`?

Comment: Wanted to add here that if you can specify the separator of values through the "sep" parameter which is what I had to use because my values were delimited by ",". So I used **lengths = scan(file = "1000x1000.txt", what = numeric(), sep = ",")** as my command.

Comment: As there are lots of similar use cases, run `?scan` to see the arguments available.